# Python search algorithm advice for MySql Table

Tags: python, mysql

I am creating an algorithm which produces a recommended hardware upgrade, based on the components of a users system.

I am trying to sort through a series of around 200 results in my database, looking for a score associated with a CPU/GPU combo.

The table looks a bit like this:

```
 CPU       GPU      SCORE   FPS
8086K   RTX 2080Ti  5311    210
7960X   RTX 2080Ti  5244    208
8700K   RTX 2080Ti  5177    205
7980XE  RTX 2080Ti  5110    202
8700K   RTX 2080Ti  5082    201
7980XE  Titan V     5038    200
8700K   RTX 2080Ti  4961    197
7900X   Titan Xp    4724    187
7700K   Titan Xp    4646    184
6950X   Titan Xp    4639    184
```

I am coding in python 3 and would implement an input myself. The input would be either the CPU or GPU parsed from a generated benchmark file.

The idea being that, if the bottleneck is found in the CPU, the GPU would be searched, to find the appropriate CPU combo which achieves the heighest score. That CPU would then be recommended first, along with the other options of lower score for compatability sake.

Essentially, I would like some help generating a search algorithm for the CPU/GPU being dealt with, then prodcing an output of associated CPU/GPU and its score.

Comment: "The idea being that, if the bottleneck is found in the CPU, the GPU would be searched, to find the appropriate CPU combo which achieves the heighest score." So a "bottleneck" for a RTX 2080Ti GPU would be the 8700K CPU??  IF somebody search with CPU 8700K  and RTX 2080 Ti it should recommend `7960X` CPU?

Comment: No, thats not how it works, the hard coded data inside the database is not to be changed. The CPU/GPU combos in the database are already free of recognisable bottlenecks. The idea is not to detect a bottleneck between the components in the database, but instead the components inside the users system, which are tested.

Comment: Your question and comment are then contradictory and or unclear to say the least.. see [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query) to provide a beter user case with expected results based on input